# Problema ao inserir dados em um banco mysql através do PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

Olá, o problema referido é que mesmo após diversas tentativas, o meu formulário não consegue inserir os dados dos clientes no banco de dados.

Aparentemente a inscrição dos dados é bem sucedida, porém nenhuma informação é inserida, e não é reportado nenhum erro apesar de tudo.

Tabela do banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
<?php

// conecta com o banco
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");

    $errors = array();

    // define as variáveis
    $nome = "";
    $data_de_nascimento = "";
    $numero_de_cadastro = "";
    $CEP = "";
    $numero = "";
    $bairro = "";
    $endereço = "";
    $cidade = "";
    $complemento = "";
    $uf = "";
    $telefone_residencial = "";
    $telefone_comercial = "";
    $categoria_de_cliente = "";
    $telefone_celular = "";
    $telefone_0800 = "";
    $CPF = "";
    $insc_estadual = "";
    $CNPJ = "";
    $RG = "";
    $insc_municipal = "";
    $PIS = "";
    $site = "";
    $email = "";
    $historico = "";

    // se o botão for clicado...
    if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
        session_start();
        // coleta os dados dos imputs
        $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nome']);
        $data_de_nascimento = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['data_de_nascimento']);
        $numero_de_cadastro = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['numero_de_cadastro']);
        $CEP = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['CEP']);
        $numero = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['numero']);
        $bairro = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bairro']);
        $endereço = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['endereço']);
        $cidade = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cidade']);
        $complemento = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['complemento']);
        $uf = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['uf']);
        $telefone_residencial = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['telefone_residencial']);
        $telefone_comercial = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['telefone_comercial']);
        $categoria_de_cliente = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['categoria_de_cliente']);
        $telefone_celular = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['telefone_celular']);
        $telefone_0800 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['telefone_0800']);
        $CPF = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['CPF']);
        $insc_estadual = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['insc_estadual']);
        $CNPJ = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['CNPJ']);
        $RG = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['RG']);
        $insc_municipal = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['insc_municipal']);
        $PIS = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['PIS']);
        $site = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['site']);
        $historico = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['historico']);

        // define cada mensagem de erro se os campos não forem preenchidos
        if (empty($nome)) { array_push($errors, "Nome é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($data_de_nascimento)) { array_push($errors, "Data de Nascimento é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($numero_de_cadastro)) { array_push($errors, "Numero de Cadastro é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($CEP)) { array_push($errors, "CEP é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($numero)) { array_push($errors, "Numero Residencial é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($bairro)) { array_push($errors, "Bairro é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($endereço)) { array_push($errors, "Endereço é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($cidade)) { array_push($errors, "Cidade é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($complemento)) { array_push($errors, "Complemento é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($uf)) { array_push($errors, "UF é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($categoria_de_cliente)) { array_push($errors, "Categoria de Cliente é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($CPF)) { array_push($errors, "CPF é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($insc_estadual)) { array_push($errors, "Inscrição Estadual é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($RG)) { array_push($errors, "RG é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($insc_municipal)) { array_push($errors, "Inscrição Municipal é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($PIS)) { array_push($errors, "PIS é obrigatório"); }

        // Grava os dados no banco
        $sql = "INSERT INTO registro(nome, data_de_nascimento, numero_de_cadastro, CEP, numero, bairro, endereço, cidade, complemento, uf, telefone_residencial, telefone_comercial, categoria_de_cliente, telefone_celular, telefone_0800, CPF, insc_estadual, CNPJ, RG, insc_municipal, PIS, site, historico) VALUES('$nome', '$data_de_nascimento', '$numero_de_cadastro', '$CEP', '$numero', '$bairro', '$endereço', '$cidade', '$complemento', '$uf', '$telefone_residencial', '$telefone_comercial', '$categoria_de_cliente', '$telefone_celular', '$telefone_0800', '$CPF', '$insc_estadual', '$CNPJ', '$RG', '$insc_municipal', '$PIS', '$site', '$historico')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        // Redireciona para outra pagina caso seja bem sucedido
        header("location: painel.php");
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro Simples</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="reg2.php" method="post">
  <? include('errors.php') ?>
  Nome:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nome" required>
  <br>
  Data de nascimento:<br>
  <input type="text" name="data_de_nascimento">
  <br>
  Numero de cadastro:<br>
  <input type="text" name="numero_de_cadastro" required>
  <br>
  CEP:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CEP" required>
  <br>
  Numero residencial:<br>
  <input type="text" name="numero" required>
  <br>
  Bairro:<br>
  <input type="text" name="bairro" required>
  <br>
  Endereço:<br>
  <input type="text" name="endereço" required>
  <br>
  Cidade:<br>
  <input type="text" name="cidade" required>
  <br>
  Numero de cadastro:<br>
  <input type="text" name="numero_de_cadastro" required>
  <br>
  Complemento:<br>
  <input type="text" name="complemento" required>
  <br>
  UF:<br>
  <input type="text" name="uf" required>
  <br>
  Telefone Residencial:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone_residencial" required>
  <br>
  Telefone Comercial:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone_comercial" required>
  <br>
  Categoria de cliente:<br>
  <input type="text" name="categoria_de_cliente" required>
  <br>
  Telefone Celular:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone_celular" required>
  <br>
  Telefone 0800:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone_0800" required>
  <br>
  CPF:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CPF" required>
  <br>
  Inscrição Estadual:<br>
  <input type="text" name="insc_estadual" required>
  <br>
  CNPJ:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CNPJ" required>
  <br>
  RG:<br>
  <input type="text" name="RG" required>
  <br>
  Inscrição Municipal:<br>
  <input type="text" name="insc_municipal" required>
  <br>
  PIS:<br>
  <input type="text" name="PIS" required>
  <br>
  Site:<br>
  <input type="text" name="site" required>
  <br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="email" required>
  <br>
  Historico:<br>
  <input type="text" name="historico" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="register_btn" value="Register">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Utilizo do WAMP SERVER.

Obrigado!

Comment: Como esta gravando a transaction? Esta utilizando o COMMIT?

Comment: Seu ambiente tá configurado para exibir todos os erros e avisos? Tente colocar uma condição na sua query: `if (!mysqli_query($db, $sql)) die('Erro na query');` porque independente de erro ou sucesso, você é redirecionado em `header("location: painel.php");`

Comment: @TiagoCasanova Estou utilizando de um COMMIT, porém não muda nada

Comment: @LipESprY Fiz como sugerido e apareceu este erro: 

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�o, cidade, complemento, uf, telefone_residencial, telefone_comercial, categori' at line 1"

Comment: @Nithogg Considere [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar essas informações. Aparentemente é problema na codificação. Repare que a `ç` não está aparecendo corretamente. Verifique se você está utilizando o mesmo charset no PHP e no banco de dados.

Comment: @LipESprY Editarei sim, bem apontado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um erro bobo, porém acabei encontrando a solução com a ajuda dos outros usuários.

Segue a solução:

Como informado nos comentários, adicionei um IF para receber o erro, sendo que a pagina era encaminhada mesmo com um problema no envio de dados.

Após, isso recebi o problema:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '�o, cidade, complemento, uf, telefone_residencial,
>   telefone_comercial, categori' at line 1

É importante ressaltar que que o carácter `ç` não está sendo procesado devido a falta de uma colação específica no código, sendo assim utilizei de um pequeno IF que define exatamente qual colação utilizar:

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($conn));
    exit;
    }
```

Assim, o próximo erro exibido foi:

> Field 'email' doesn't have a default value

Sendo que apenas não tinha adicionado a variável do input EMAIL para ser inserida na db, após essa correção, as informações são inseridas normalmente no banco.

Sendo assim, o código atualizado:

```
<?php

// conecta com o banco
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");

if (!mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8')) {
    printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($db));
    exit;
  }

    $errors = array();

  $erro = array();

    // define as variáveis
      $nome = "";
    $data_de_nascimento = "";
    $numero_de_cadastro = "";
    $CEP = "";
    $numero = "";
    $bairro = "";
    $endereço = "";
    $cidade = "";
    $complemento = "";
    $uf = "";
    $telefone_residencial = "";
    $telefone_comercial = "";
    $categoria_de_cliente = "";
    $telefone_celular = "";
    $telefone_0800 = "";
    $CPF = "";
    $insc_estadual = "";
    $CNPJ = "";
    $RG = "";
    $insc_municipal = "";
    $PIS = "";
    $site = "";
    $email = "";
    $historico = "";

    // se o botão for clicado...
    if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
        session_start();
        // coleta os dados dos imputs
        $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nome']);
        $data_de_nascimento = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['data_de_nascimento']);
        $numero_de_cadastro = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['numero_de_cadastro']);
        $CEP = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['CEP']);
        $numero = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['numero']);
        $bairro = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['bairro']);
        $endereço = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['endereço']);
        $cidade = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cidade']);
        $complemento = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['complemento']);
        $uf = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['uf']);
        $telefone_residencial = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['telefone_residencial']);
        $telefone_comercial = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['telefone_comercial']);
        $categoria_de_cliente = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['categoria_de_cliente']);
        $telefone_celular = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['telefone_celular']);
        $telefone_0800 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['telefone_0800']);
        $CPF = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['CPF']);
        $insc_estadual = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['insc_estadual']);
        $CNPJ = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['CNPJ']);
        $RG = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['RG']);
        $insc_municipal = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['insc_municipal']);
        $PIS = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['PIS']);
        $site = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['site']);
        $historico = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['historico']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);

        // define cada mensagem de erro se os campos não forem preenchidos
        if (empty($nome)) { array_push($errors, "Nome é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($data_de_nascimento)) { array_push($errors, "Data de Nascimento é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($numero_de_cadastro)) { array_push($errors, "Numero de Cadastro é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($CEP)) { array_push($errors, "CEP é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($numero)) { array_push($errors, "Numero Residencial é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($bairro)) { array_push($errors, "Bairro é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($endereço)) { array_push($errors, "Endereço é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($cidade)) { array_push($errors, "Cidade é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($complemento)) { array_push($errors, "Complemento é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($uf)) { array_push($errors, "UF é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($categoria_de_cliente)) { array_push($errors, "Categoria de Cliente é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($CPF)) { array_push($errors, "CPF é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($insc_estadual)) { array_push($errors, "Inscrição Estadual é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($RG)) { array_push($errors, "RG é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($insc_municipal)) { array_push($errors, "Inscrição Municipal é obrigatório"); }
        if (empty($PIS)) { array_push($errors, "PIS é obrigatório"); }

        // Grava os dados no banco
        $sql = "INSERT INTO registro(nome, data_de_nascimento, numero_de_cadastro, CEP, numero, bairro, endereço, cidade, complemento, uf, telefone_residencial, telefone_comercial, categoria_de_cliente, telefone_celular, telefone_0800, CPF, insc_estadual, CNPJ, RG, insc_municipal, PIS, site, historico, email) VALUES('$nome', '$data_de_nascimento', '$numero_de_cadastro', '$CEP', '$numero', '$bairro', '$endereço', '$cidade', '$complemento', '$uf', '$telefone_residencial', '$telefone_comercial', '$categoria_de_cliente', '$telefone_celular', '$telefone_0800', '$CPF', '$insc_estadual', '$CNPJ', '$RG', '$insc_municipal', '$PIS', '$site', '$historico', '$email')";
        if (!mysqli_query($db, $sql)) die(mysqli_error($db));
        // Redireciona para outra pagina caso seja bem sucedido
        header("location: painel.php");
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro Simples</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="reg2.php" method="post">
  <? include('errors.php') ?>
  Nome:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nome" required>
  <br>
  Data de nascimento:<br>
  <input type="text" name="data_de_nascimento">
  <br>
  Numero de cadastro:<br>
  <input type="text" name="numero_de_cadastro" required>
  <br>
  CEP:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CEP" required>
  <br>
  Numero residencial:<br>
  <input type="text" name="numero" required>
  <br>
  Bairro:<br>
  <input type="text" name="bairro" required>
  <br>
  Endereço:<br>
  <input type="text" name="endereço" required>
  <br>
  Cidade:<br>
  <input type="text" name="cidade" required>
  <br>
  Numero de cadastro:<br>
  <input type="text" name="numero_de_cadastro" required>
  <br>
  Complemento:<br>
  <input type="text" name="complemento" required>
  <br>
  UF:<br>
  <input type="text" name="uf" required>
  <br>
  Telefone Residencial:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone_residencial" required>
  <br>
  Telefone Comercial:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone_comercial" required>
  <br>
  Categoria de cliente:<br>
  <input type="text" name="categoria_de_cliente" required>
  <br>
  Telefone Celular:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone_celular" required>
  <br>
  Telefone 0800:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telefone_0800" required>
  <br>
  CPF:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CPF" required>
  <br>
  Inscrição Estadual:<br>
  <input type="text" name="insc_estadual" required>
  <br>
  CNPJ:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CNPJ" required>
  <br>
  RG:<br>
  <input type="text" name="RG" required>
  <br>
  Inscrição Municipal:<br>
  <input type="text" name="insc_municipal" required>
  <br>
  PIS:<br>
  <input type="text" name="PIS" required>
  <br>
  Site:<br>
  <input type="text" name="site" required>
  <br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="email" required>
  <br>
  Historico:<br>
  <input type="text" name="historico" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="register_btn" value="Register">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Esta solução só foi possível graças a grande ajuda nos comentários da pergunta.

Obrigado!